# Setting ParseACL to a new ParseObject null reference issue

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

I am currently getting a NullReferenceException when trying to set a ParseACL object to a ParseObject that I create.

```
var po = new ParseObject("Table");
po.ACL = new ParseACL(ParseUser.CurrentUser);
```

This is in a project that I created before the summer, and picked up again now. This code worked before, but now it crashes. I cannot figure out why it is giving this error message now.

Using Parse SDK 1.6.2 for C# / Xamarin.

Comment: Please add a summarised version of the GitHub issue you linked to in your question as an **answer**. Questions should contain the question, only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in the current Parse .NET SDK 1.6.2. Reported the bug, the fix will be available in the next version of the SDK.

Temporary workaround given by *richardjrossiii*:

> As a temporary work around until the next SDK version is released, you can create a concrete subclass of ParseObject, and register that, and then the ACL, ObjectId, CreatedAt, and UpdatedAt properties will work properly once again.

Source: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/90